# Which Israeli Banks has NZ Super-Annuation Fund divested from due to their support for settlement activity on the Occupied Territories?

Tags: israel, palestine, citizen-activism

The NZ Super-Annuation Fund (the state pension fund in New Zealand) has recently divested from five Israeli banks due to their support for settlement activity in the Occupied Territories.

Which five banks are these and how much has been divested from each?

Answer (score 3):

I [found this](https://www.nzsuperfund.nz/news-and-media/israeli-bank-exclusions/):

| Company | NZ$ value of divested holdings |
| --- | --- |
| First International Bank of Israel | $ 856,971.65 |
| Israel Discount Bank | $ 1,049,063.83 |
| Bank Hapoalim | $ 2,100,072.45 |
| Bank Leumi | $ 2,407,309.85 |
| Bank Mizrahi-Tefahot | $ 927,205.18 |
| **Total** | **$ 6,528,441.54** |

Comment: Doesn't seem like a lot of money, on a national scale.

Comment: Plus there is this [article about HRW](https://time.com/4183059/why-human-rights-watch-is-urging-companies-to-pull-out-of-israeli-settlements/)

Comment: [And this](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/12/27/hsbc-divests-from-israeli-arms-company-elbit-systems) HSBC investment of almost 4 million British pounds.

Comment: [And demonstrations against Barclay's](https://bdsmovement.net/news/target-barclays-action-pull-out-israel-and-arms-trade)